# Text below buttons in android

Tags: button, android

I have an application which has many icons (Buttons). I want to put a text below the icons (just like mainscreen). My icon size is 128x128 for high resolution, so android:drawableTop strategy doesnt work because I couldnt figure out a way of programmatically reducing the size of the drawable to 80x80dp. I would prefer not to create several little icon files.

Another idea offered was to put a text view below each button. This is possible but sounds very clunky way of achieving this.

Could someone suggest a way of achieving a text below the icons ?

Thanks

Comment: "I would prefer not to create several little icon files" --- I would translate this to : "I would prefer not to follow standard best practices"

Comment: Sarwar ... sarcasm doesnt help me or anyone so please keep it to yourself., My project already has a lot of images and creating several more for icons will increase the size of project. Standard best practice is not always "The best practice".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would use this layout structure for your purpose

```
<LinearLayout>
<Button/>
<TextView/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: This worked. Tried to vote up but I am not allowed. Thanks again for the answer